# how can you turn off instagram notifications?

Tags: notification-bar, samsung-galaxy-gio, instagram

I have a galaxy gio and i was asking myself if it was possible to shut up the notifications coming up continuosly in the upper bar of the display. Is it possible and if so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you long press on the notification and select app info then you can untick the show notifications box.